# SSIS Expression to look for character

Tags: expression, ssis

I am using SSIS 2008.

I want an Expression for a Column where it must look to see if the Value coming in contains a period.

If it does not contain a period it must add a .00 at the end of the value.

Example.

```
123.00 Stays 123.00
435 becomes 435.00
```

[image]

Comment: What is the data type for the column ?

Comment: String going into decimal(6,2)

Comment: If its getting stored as `decimal(6,2)` then `.00` will be inserted

Comment: For some reason it does not......and my ssis package fail.

Comment: use `convert(column,decimal(6,2)` in Data conversion or at the source itself

Comment: Nope, still does not want to do the trick hey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this expression in `Derived Column`

```
FINDSTRING(Column,".",1) != 0 ? column : column + ".00"
```

[image]